# Find the necessary and sufficient condition for $f_n(x)=b_nx+c_nx^2$ to converge uniformly to 0 on the real line is

Tags: real-analysis

**[CSIR_UGC_NET_2014_December]**

> Let $\{b_n\}$ and $\{c_n\}$ be sequence of real numbers. Then the
>   necessary and sufficient condition for $f_n(x)=b_nx+c_nx^2$ to
>   converge uniformly to 0 on the real line is
>
> (1) $\lim _{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n=0$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty
> > }c_n=0$
>
> (2) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|b_n|<\infty$ and
>   $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|c_n|<\infty$
>
> (3) There exists a positive integer $N$ such that $b_n=0$ and $c_n=0$
>   for all $n>N$
>
> (4) $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}c_n=0$.

If we choose $b_n=c_n=\frac{1}{n}$, then $f_n$ not converge uniformly to 0. For option (2) i have taken $b_n=c_n=\frac{1}{n^2}.$ I guess option $3$ is true, please help me to get correct option.

Comment: You are correct (good reasoning in your elimination). Can you see why it is true?

Comment: no, but i hope it is easy to prove

Comment: If $f_n \rightarrow 0$ uniformly then $|f_n (x)|<1$ for all x and n sufficiently large. But the only bounded polynomials are constants so $f_n$  is a constant for n sufficiently large. Since these polynomials vanish at 0 we get $f_n=0$ n sufficiently large. This gives 3)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, (3) is correct. It's clearly sufficient. To show necessity: Assume you have the given $M$ (in the definition of uniform convergence of $(f_n)$) s.t. $|f_n|<1$ (taking $\epsilon = 1$) for all $x$. If the $c_n$'s aren't zero from some point on you can find $m>M$ s.t. $c_m\neq 0$. The idea is to take $x=1/\sqrt{|c_m|}$. There are two cases, whether $c_m$ positive or negative. But you can control with the sign of $x$ s.t. the terms have the same sign, that is, if $c_m$ and $b_m$ have the same sign (or $b_m=0$), use positive $x$ and choose $y=x$; if they have different signs, use $y=-x$. Now (since the terms $b_my $ and $ c_my^2$ have same sign) we have

$$|f_n(y)| = |b_my + c_my^2| \geq |c_mx^2| = 1,$$
a contradiction.

Now you know that the $c_n$'s must be zero from some point on. Same idea (now even easier) for the $b_n$'s.

Comment: Can you explain, Why $|f_n|\geq |c_mx^2|$?

Comment: I edited my answer. Hope it's more clear now.